# How can I visualize a stim circuit?

Tags: programming, stim

Is there any function I can call to visualize a stim circuit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since v1.10, you can use [`stim.Circuit.diagram`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.diagram) to visualize the circuit.

```
import stim

circuit = stim.Circuit("""
    QUBIT_COORDS(0, 0) 0
    QUBIT_COORDS(0, 1) 1
    QUBIT_COORDS(1, 0) 2
    QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 3
    R 0 1 2 3
    H 0 2
    CNOT 0 1
    CNOT 2 3
    M 0 1 2 3
""")

print(circuit.diagram())
```

> ```
> q0: -QUBIT_COORDS(0,0)-R-H-@-M:rec[0]-
>                            |
> q1: -QUBIT_COORDS(0,1)-R---X-M:rec[1]-
>
> q2: -QUBIT_COORDS(1,0)-R-H-@-M:rec[2]-
>                            |
> q3: -QUBIT_COORDS(1,1)-R---X-M:rec[3]-
> ```

You can also get an SVG image of the timeline:

```
circuit.to_diagram(type="timeline-svg")
```

In Jupyter notebooks this SVG will display inline. Otherwise you have to print it to a .svg file then open it.

> [image]

or a 3d model, optionally embedded into a viewer that can be opened in a web browser:

```
# for this one you really want to have specified qubit coords
circuit.to_diagram(type="timeline-3d-html")
```

> [image]

In Jupyter notebooks this viewer will display inline in the cell output. Otherwise you have to print it to a .html file then open it.

The diagram types that are currently available are:

```
    timeline-text
    timeline-svg
    timeline-3d
    timeline-3d-html
    match-graph-svg
    match-graph-3d
    match-graph-3d-html
    detector-slice-text
    detector-slice-svg
```

You can also use the `stimcirq` package to convert into a cirq circuit and get diagrams that way (e.g. with the `cirq_web` package).

Comment: I notice when I have detectors in a stim circuit, the 3d visualization of `cirq_web` can not work properly. Is that true I must delete all the detectors for visualization with `cirq_web`?

Comment: @Inm That sounds like a bug in `cirq_web` to me; it should be ignoring operations with no targets. But yes, filtering out the bad instructions would avoid the problem.

Comment: @Inm I reported the bug: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/5172

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stimcirq](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/glue/cirq/README.md) to convert your Stim circuit into a Cirq circuit then visualize it:

```
import stim
import stimcirq

cirq_circuit = stimcirq.stim_circuit_to_cirq_circuit(stim_circuit)
print(cirq_circuit)
```